# Quotient ring, quick question

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do I read R \ {0}, R modulo zero? With R being the Real number ring. Is this just the Real number ring R without zero?

Comment: R without zero. The backslash, drawn using the command `\setminus` in latex, means the set difference. I read the symbol as "without", so R without zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \in \mathbb R - \{0\}$ then $x \in \mathbb R$ and $x \notin \{0\}$. That is, $x$ is a real number different from zero.

If otherwise you mean $\mathbb R/\langle0\rangle =\frac{\mathbb R}{\langle0\rangle}$ then is the set of equivalence classes such that $[x] = [y] \Leftrightarrow x - y \in \langle 0\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

The notation $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ means all non-zero reals, often also written as $\mathbb{R}^{\ast}$.

A very technical way to read it would be the set difference of the set of reals numbers and the set containing zero. Yet hardly anybody would say it like this.

One might say the reals without $0$ or even the non-zero reals.

The noation $\mathbb{R} / \{0\}$ could be read as $\mathbb{R}$ modulo $0$ or also as the quotient group of the reals by the trivial subgroup. This however should appear rarely in practice as taking a quotient by the trivial subgroup is not very interesting, basically just yielding the original group.